# DIV width: auto is 0 pixel

Tags: html, css, width

I'm new in CSS and have not not found the solution for this basic problem. I have 3 divs in one line. The center div must have fixed width and it's position also fixed px from the center. I need auto width for the left and right div to fill the space at the left/right side. Here is my try but the left and right divs are zero width. Thanks for the help!

```css
.fullwidth{
    width:100%
    height:20px;
}
.left{
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    width: auto;
}
.center{
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
 margin-right:100px;    
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
}
.right{
    background:blue;
    float:right;
    height:20px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is known as the [flexible box model design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), it is fairly new so there are some [vendor prefix requirements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) although I have emitted them for simplicity. You may have noticed that there is poor support for Internet Explorer so if that's a concern you may need to look for alternatives. Regardless take a look of it in use:

```css
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.left {background-color: green;}
.center {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
.right {background: blue;}
.left,.right {flex: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to move the center to to left 100px... how can I do that? https://jsfiddle.net/y3u2u3z0/

Comment: Ah I missed that, @Paulie-D's answer will help you with that :)

Answer (score 0):

`flexbox` can do that.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KddOex) - Click "View Compiled" for all vendor prefixes

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fullwidth {
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.fullwidth .left,
.fullwidth .right {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
}
.center {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
}
.line {
  /* center point reference for demo only */
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>

</div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```css
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
.fullwidth div {
  float: left
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
}
.center {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```